# Logic error for prime numbers

Tags: logic, primes

I have attempted to rewrite a program I had for finding whether a number was prime or not, into a function. 
Currently I just output 1 or 2 just for testing purposes.

The problem is that p = 1 no matter what number is input.

Thanks to anyone with some insight.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int is_prime(int num);

int main()
{
        int num, pr=0;


        printf("Enter a positive number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        printf("prime is %d ",is_prime(pr));
        return 0;
}

int is_prime(int n )
{
        int p, i, count=0;


        for (i=2; i<=n/2; i++)
        {
                if(n%i==0)
                {
                        count++;
                        break;
                }
        }
        if (count==0 && n!=1)
                p=1;
        else
                p=2;
        return p;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your function has the wrong name (`is_primei` instead of `is_prime`).
2. You are always passing 0 to the function (`pr` specifically) instead of the input value `num`.

Comment: thanks. the first part was due to me copying an older version of the code before removing that typo.